# What are the Windows Station and Desktop objects?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, terminal-services

I've read this link...

- MSDN: [Window Stations and Desktops](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687098(v=vs.85).aspx)

...but I don't understand. What are they? And what are their functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Stations and Desktops are securable objects. Their primary function is to act as a security partition/barrier for various resources and features such as the clipboard, [hooks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx), [registered messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947(v=vs.85).aspx) and the [global atom table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649053(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Global_Atom_Table). Sessions were added at the top of this tree when the [Terminal Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755399(v=ws.10).aspx)/Remote desktop feature was added to Windows. Sessions are also used by the fast user switching feature.

The hierarchy looks something like this:

```
+ Session for services (Session 0)
| + Window Station  ("Service-xyz...")
|    + Desktop
|
+ Session for user "Foo"
|  + Window Station ("winsta0")
|    + Desktop ("Default")
|    | + Taskbar and applications
|    + Desktop ("Winlogon")
|    | + Logon/lock screen
|    + Desktop ("Screen-saver", created on demand)
|      + Secure screen saver
|
+ Session for user "Bar"
|  + Window Station ("winsta0")
|    + Desktop ("Default")
|    | + Taskbar and applications
|    + Desktop ("Winlogon")
|      + Logon/lock screen
```

> The interactive window station is named winsta0, and is [the only](https://www.microsoft.com/msj/0599/security/security0599.aspx)
> station that can receive mouse and keyboard input from the interactive
> user.

In Vista and later, [services run in their own session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb203962(v=vs.85).aspx).

Because journal recording and hooks are per-desktop a normal application cannot listen to the keyboard input when you type in your logon password or accept a [UAC prompt](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uac/2006/05/03/user-account-control-prompts-on-the-secure-desktop/) because Windows (winlogon.exe) switches to a different desktop under these conditions.

There are [various tools](http://www.ikriv.com/dev/cpp/EnumWinstaGui/) tools that lets you explore the Window Station and Desktop objects. SysInternals also [wrote a tool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881) that uses/abuses Desktop objects to create virtual desktops.

Although it is from 2000, the "[Programming Windows Security](http://pluralsight.com/books/pws/default.htm)" book by [Keith Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Brown_(author)) might still be the best resource if you want to know more...

#### Further reading

- 2007-07-24, Microsoft TechNet, Craig Marcho, [*Sessions, Desktops and Windows Stations*](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/sessions-desktops-and-windows-stations/ba-p/372473) (Archived [here](https://archive.ph/wip/wK5uO).)