# Last Logon timestamp gets changed for admin users whenever run as administartor action triggered

Tags: windows, uac

I logged in to my Windows 7 Enterprise machine by **tests** user which is **standard** user and runs command to check last logon info. Pleaser refer below output.

**>net user tests | findstr "logon"**

**Last logon                   9/16/2021 12:18:17 PM**

Then I run same command for **testa** user which is **administrator** user for same machine.

**>net user testa | findstr "logon"**

**Last logon                   9/16/2021 11:36:17 PM**

Till now **net user** was showing expected information. Later I started services.msc with **run as
administrator** by providing **testa** user's credentials, and again executed same command. But this time last logon timestamp was changed as mentioned below.

**>net user testa | findstr "logon"**

**Last logon                   9/16/2021 12:19:17 PM**

So, Please anyone can help me with explanation what's happening here because mostly I worked in linux platform quite new to windows.

Does windows starts session for admin users whenever **run as administrator** action is triggered ?

Does there is any better way to find out **last logon time** for all users in windows ?

Answer (score 0):

There are in a way two types of logons.

The "full" type of logon where a user clicks their name to log in and a new [TS session+window station+desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449220/3501) is created and their shell (usually Explorer.exe) is started.

The other type of logon where the `LogonUser` function (or other related functions that require username and password) is called. This function creates a token that represents the user and their groups and privileges. The "full" logon also calls this function.

The Net API (and net.exe) is simply telling you about the last `LogonUser` authentication event.

I'm sure there are ways to figure out the "other" type of logon event as well but nothing pops into my head right now.

Programatically you could create a NT service and get notified about session changes (look at the WTS* API).

Comment: Thanks @Andres, you have explained very nicely.