# Launch my application before the Windows logon screen

Tags: windows, delphi

In a personal project, I want to display my application before (or above) the Windows Logon, ie just before entering the Windows password.

The application must "hide" the password entry screen. I used to launch an application at Windows startup but this after viewing the Windows desktop.

Is it possible to do this please? Should I create a Windows service that will launch my application?
Thanks for your help

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/credential-providers-in-windows#custom-credential-providers

Comment: "_The application must "hide" the password entry screen_" - any sane operating system will deny such an attempt. I'm afraid you have to go back to Windows 95 to halfway achieve that...

Comment: @ami *"any sane operating system will deny such an attempt"* - Why? Do you, perhaps, not understand, how access control works in Windows?

Comment: @ amigo : "any sane operating system will deny such an attempt". It depends on the operating system itself. If I remember correctly, before the Windows logon was displayed, we were almost under DOS.

Comment: @IInspectable Care to elaborate on "_access control_" as that can mean anything? Do you have an example where displaying your own window on top of Windows' logon screen can be achieved? At the time of writing i.e. in Win10?

Comment: Wait: do you mean the whole **logon** screen? Or do you mean the logon screen should be displayed while you **only** want to hide its password **edit control** (aka [clickjacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking))? The latter one is what I interpreted, hence my comment.

Comment: @ amigo : There is a lot of software that does this like "KeyLemon", "Luxand Blink", ... That's what I want to do. How do you think these softwares do this? . That's what I want to do with Delphi.

Comment: @amigo :the login screen will be displayed but the user will not be able to enter the password. This is when my application is displayed with a whole screen: TForm = wsMaximized

Comment: Generic replacement of the logon UI ended with server 2003, in Vista GINA was replaced by credential providers and they cannot fully replace the GUI like GINA did.

Comment: @ Anders. Ok. the Windows Logon screen is displayed normally but with some modifications: display of my application even in a small window. I want to do like "luxand blink". How does "luxand blink" do this?

Answer (score 0):

If this is just a personal project on your own machine you could set Windows to [autologon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon) and then just run your application like a normal startup shortcut.

A [NT service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/services) is the only documented way to run code before a user logs on. However, spawning a new process in another session and interacting with the [Winlogon desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449220/3501) and putting yourself on top of LogonUI.exe is going to be a hack.

Comment: @ Anders :Yes, this is a personal project. it is an "autologon" solution.
So like I said in my post, a windows service is the only way to do this.